# developing outlook add-in, to check if the sent mail item has been replied to

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, outlook-addin

So,

I want to check if the mail I sent to someone, has a reply. In other words, if that person has replied to my mail.

```
sentboxFolder = 

ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentbox);

//So here if i access individual mail and check

Outlook.MailItem mailItem = ( Outlook.MailItem ) sentboxFolder.Items[1];
```

Now, if i took the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED property of this mail item, what would it return if the mail has a reply sitting somewhere in my inbox and what would it return if noone replied to my mail ?

Also,

I'm not sure if I'd be able to implement this properly, can someone refer me to some examples where PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED is used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED is only set on the messages in your local mailbox. If a recipient replied to the message, PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED will be set on a message in his/her mailbox, which you most likely cannot access.

You can try to read PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX property from the message in the sent items folder, then search for a message in the Inbox folder that has PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX starting with the same value.

See the following article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx